# JS two Layer Filter works but get loop after clicking too many filter. Browser crashes

Tags: javascript, function, loops, filter

I wrote a little filter to click 3 different lvl 1 filter and 3 different lvl 2 filters. On every click at one filter it should show the result of each filter. But after clicking a few times, the browser starts getting slower and slower. I put an alert in it and found out, that everytime i click an filter the function runs 2 times -> 4 times -> 8 times -> 16 times. So if I click maybe 30 times the filter, the browser collapse.
Pls. help

Greetings Max

```
 var fil1 = "";
    var fil2 = "";
    var filcomp = "";

$(function func() {




/*Filter 1*/
$("#Filter_btn_1").click(function () {
    fil1 = ".filter_option1";
    filter();
});
$("#Filter_btn_2").click(function () {
    fil1 = ".filter_option2";
    filter();
});
$("#Filter_btn_3").click(function () {
    fil1 = ".filter_option3";
    filter();
});

/*Filter 2*/
$("#Filter_btn_4").click(function () {
    fil2 = ".filter_option4";
    filter();
});
$("#Filter_btn_5").click(function () {
    fil2 = ".filter_option5";
    filter();
});
$("#Filter_btn_6").click(function () {
    fil2 = ".filter_option6";
    filter();
});



filcomp = fil1 + fil2;



$('.filter_btn').click(function () {
    $(".filter_btn").removeClass("filter_selected");
    $(this).addClass("filter_selected");
});

$('.filter_btn2').click(function () {
    $(".filter_btn2").removeClass("filter_selected");
    $(this).addClass("filter_selected");
});


$('.filter_reset_btn').click(function () {
    location.reload();

});

function filter() {
    alert(filcomp);
    func();
    $(".post").hide();
    $("div").filter(filcomp).show();
};

});
```

Comment: Why do you have everything wrapped in func which is called by filter, when filter is a function within func?

I'd probably start by removing func altogether and instead set filcomp inside filter, as filter is called when clicking a button anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i usesd

```
var counter =0;

if(counter==0){            
        function filter() { 
            counter = 1;
            func();
            $(".career_post").hide();
            $("div").filter(filcomp).show();
            return counter;
        };
};
```